# Get education history by id Facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to extract Facebook user profile by GraphAPI. From the query:"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/search?q=vietnam&limit=1000&offset=0&type=user&format=json&access_token=....". I can get the list of id Facebook. But I want more information about user profile such as education, email. I used query:"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{id_user}?fields= education,birthday&access_token=...."But I cant get them. Any suggestions for my problem? I will highly appreciated

Comment: is this of any use to you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user (found it by googling your question title)

Comment: Put some code you tried, it will help users for asking you a solution.

Comment: I used 2 ways to get profile from id facebook. + using Graph API Explore with 101609236......?fields=id,name,education --> {
  "id": "101609236........", "name": "Nam ...."} + using sdk-facebook >>> import facebook
>>> graph = facebook.GraphAPI(".....w7TBo2hxq9G2I4xEQQZDZD")
>>> user = graph.get_object("10160923.................")
>>> print user
{u'first_name': u'Nam', u'last_name': u'....', u'name': u'Nam ...', u'updated_time': u'2016-02-08T14:45:45+0000', u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10160923....../', u'id': u'10160923..........'}

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain more detailed infos such as 'education', 'birthday' and 'email', you need an access token with permissions that will grant you access to that info.

From the graph API explorer, with the token you get by default, using the following query:

```
me?fields=id,name,education,email,birthday
```

will not return education, email or birthday

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "name": "..."
}
```

Using the Graph API Explorer tool, you can try the same query with more priviledges.
Click the "Get Token" button, then on the prompt you get, check the following permissions:

```
user_birthday
user_education_history
email (located inside "extended permissions")
```

then try the request again. You should get:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "email": "...@....com",
  "birthday": "../../...."
  "education": ...
}
```

**NOTE:** You may not get all fields, depending on wether the target user has made these fields available to you.
Also if the user you're querying is 'yourself' (/me) then the user must have granted these permissions to your app. (a user may decline individual permissions. Your app must take that in consideration and handle cases where permissions were refused.)

Once you've confirmed this works, all you have to do is to add these permissions to your login or authorization flow inside your app.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can get my profile but I cannot get profile of another id. Would you hepl me solve this problem, Thanks again

Comment: @HoaiNguyen You can only get the birthday, email and education of another id if either A) they have made that information public on their profile  or B) You log in as that user.